# Using Python request post method but getting 401 response code

Tags: python, post, request

I am using Python request module post method to process json data, like so.

```
r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers)
```

However I am getting `response[401]`. Does it mean I need to first authorize it 
by adding login first?

Comment: Can you add your authorization in your code?

Comment: without more info it is impossible to answer

Comment: 401 means you need to authorize ... what part dont you understan ... what api are you consuming ...

Comment: sorry!, I first did response = requests.get('http://bla.bla.bla.bla,

Comment: well there you go ... `bla.blah.blah` Im sure is not the correct address... also you typically need to open the authorization url in a web browser that redirects the autorization token back to a specified url

Comment: I use HTTPBasicAuth(user, password) that give me response code of 200 , but when doing post, response code of 401 came back. How to keep them in one session?

Comment: @PeterChao you can use `s = requests.session()`

Answer (score 15):

A `401` response, as you noticed, means that you need to authenticate in order to make the request. How you do this depends on the auth system in place, but your comment "I use HTTPBasicAuth(user, password) that give me response code of 200" suggests that it's just Basic Auth - which is easy to deal with in `requests`.

Anywhere you do a `requests` call, add the kwarg `auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD)` - so for your example above, you'd do `r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))` (replacing USERNAME and PASSWORD with the right values, as shown [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/).

Comment: I can access the url using my explorer, but I dont know what my authentication is. How can I use "requests" to get url content by leveraging the explorer in my computer.